# Getting Video Duration from ALAsset

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Hi I'm new to objective C. I'm using AGImagePicker to pick images and video files from phone library and displaying them in GridView. but now I want to get duration of video file to display it with video thumbnail. I don't know how to get video duration from ALAsset. Anybody Please. Any type of answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

**1)To get the Media Duration with the Help of ALAssetPropertyDuration**

```
double value = [[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDuration] doubleValue]; //Find the Duraion
[cell.lblMediaLength setText:[self timeFormatted:value]];
```

**2)Method that convert the Total seconds to Hour:min:sec**

```
- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(double)totalSeconds

    {
        NSTimeInterval timeInterval = totalSeconds;
        long seconds = lroundf(timeInterval); // Modulo (%) operator below needs int or long
        int hour = 0;
        int minute = seconds/60.0f;
        int second = seconds % 60;
        if (minute > 59) {
            hour = minute/60;
            minute = minute%60;
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second];
        }
        else{
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minute, second];
        }
    }
```

**For Swift**

```
func timeFormatted(totalSeconds: Float64) -> String {
        let timeInterval: NSTimeInterval = totalSeconds
        let seconds: Int = lround(timeInterval)
        var hour: Int = 0
        var minute: Int = Int(seconds/60)
        let second: Int = seconds % 60
        if minute > 59 {
            hour = minute / 60
            minute = minute % 60
            return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second)
        }
        else {
            return String(format: "%02d:%02d", minute, second)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If `asset` is an `ALAsset`:

```
NSNumber *number = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDuration];
```

This will return an NSNumber. If you want the value:

```
double value = [[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDuration] doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I get the duration.

```
AVAsset *testAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
return testAsset.duration;
```